# Python - How to use blender operators (bpy.ops) on blender context data (bpy.context)?

Tags: python, operator

I want to use for example `bpy.ops.outliner.collection_isolate` on one of collections in my scene
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do with active collection

```
import bpy

# get first outliner, Make sure it has outliner in the workspace or you will get an error
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'OUTLINER':
        break

with bpy.context.temp_override(area=area):
    bpy.ops.outliner.collection_isolate()
```

Comment: Will it work without UI loaded? (from OS console)

Comment: I think Probably not.